# Remove span in a div class to convert the string to a number and make calulcations

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class = "s3">
  <span>
      "         Price: "
      <strong>2000.00</strong>
      <span class = "avg">
        "         Avg Price: "
          </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the number between strong and multiply it by 0.15 then replace the original value with the new value using javascript

```html
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("s3");


    var i;
    var counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    
      var valueString  = x[0].innerHTML.replace(/Price:/g,"");
   
        counter = parseFloat(valueString);
  
        var j = (counter*0.15);
        x[i].innerHTML = (j);


 
    }
```

An example of the innerHTML would be $2000 and I want to take that number and multiply it by 0.15 and replace the value with the calculated number. EX: 2000.00 -> 300.00

This code only gets rid of the Price: and spaces, but I need it to remove the strong and span class "avg" in order to convert the string to a number using parseFloat. I'm not sure how to go about this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0]` to get the contents of the strong tag. Your `valueString` variable contained the entire HTML content of the `s3` div exluding the "Price:" string. In future it is a good idea to use `console.log()` to check what a variable contains to help debug the issue.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("s3");


var i;
var counter = 0;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  var valueString = x[i].getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].innerHTML;

    counter = parseFloat(valueString);

    var j = (counter*0.15).toFixed(2);
    x[i].innerHTML = (j);



}
```

```html
    <div class = "s3">
      <span>
          "         Price: "
          <strong>2000.00</strong>
          <span class = "avg">
            "         Avg Price: "
              </span>
       </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!!!! I also meant to ask how I can make the calculated number show 2 decimals

Comment: You can use `(value).toFixed(2);`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM APIs [`document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) would come in handy here.

You can use these to access the `<strong>` DOM nodes directly instead of having to parse out other HTML, etc.

```js
var numLabels = document.querySelectorAll('.s3 strong');

for(var label of numLabels) {
  var value = parseFloat(label.innerText);
  label.innerText = (value * 0.15).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="s3">
  <span>
      "         Price: "
      <strong>2000.00</strong>
      <span class = "avg">
        "         Avg Price: "
          </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="s3">
  <span>
      "         Price: "
      <strong>1000.00</strong>
      <span class = "avg">
        "         Avg Price: "
          </span>
  </span>
</div>
```